# As I promised vs As I promised to

Tags: verbs

When do we use "to" after the verb before an omission? Because I promised or because I promised to? Because I want or beacause I want to?

Is the "to" optional?

Comment: It depends on which verb you're using.

Comment: Could you elaborate on this a bit?

Comment: In spoken English, "want" in this situation is always used with "to". With "promise" in this case, "to" is optional. I would find either way acceptable with "promise", although there may be people who feel differently. To me, "promised" and "promised to" both sound natural. There are other verbs that have this issue, for example, "like", which in the kind of case you cite, needs "to". So you may want to try searching online for various verbs to see what prepositions they take and in what cases.